# I'm new to spring, facing this issue while connecting springboot and mysql-db through spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm getting this error while i hit the endpoint in postman

---

2021-07-08 16:21:36.244  WARN 11140 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2021-07-08 16:21:36.244 ERROR 11140 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'products0_.product_id' in 'field list'
2021-07-08 16:21:36.258  INFO 11140 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'products0_.product_id' in 'field list'

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'products0_.product_id' in 'field list'

**entity**

```
@Entity
public class Products {
    @Id
    private String productId;
    private String productName;
    private double price;
    private String ownerId;
    private String imageURL;
    private String inStock;
}
//with getter setter and constructors
```

**ProductsServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.akilan.juztradeapi.service;
import com.akilan.juztradeapi.entity.Products;
import com.akilan.juztradeapi.repo.ProductsRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ProductsServiceImpl implements ProductsService {
   @Autowired
    private ProductsRepo productsRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Products> findAllProducts() {
        return productsRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void createDepartment(Products products) {
        productsRepo.save(products);
    }
}
```

**ProductsRepo**

```
package com.akilan.juztradeapi.repo;

import com.akilan.juztradeapi.entity.Products;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProductsRepo extends JpaRepository<Products,String> {
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
```

Comment: i think you forgot to mention data source URL like this one spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/some_db

Comment: go through this example for better understanding - https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Comment: thanks @sunilkushwah i missed the ddl autoupdate in application.properties which was required to create tables automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**thanks for your help,**
the problem is that I missed this property which is required to create tables authomatically.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tab
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```